# Small balloon/box appear near nofityicon

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I once have noticied when my Adobe Reader was updating, I saw a small balloon like it always has been. But then I wondered how I could make one of my own balloon/box/border things near my notifyicon. In XAML, I need a small ballon/box/border to appear near a notifyicon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NotifyIcon to set up baloon tips.  But if you want something which looks a bit cooler check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx. Looking at the screenshots there you should do that for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find more information:

For hacking it onto the Win32 API:
http://codeproject.com/csharp/notifyballoon.asp

Using XAML:
http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon